# Integrating KeyVault access into VSTS Release task

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-keyvault

I am trying to figure out what is involved to write a console application that will run as part of a VSTS Release task and that program will read a connection string (secret) from a preconfigured keyvault and then connect to an Azure SQL db using that connection string and apply some changes.

Currently I have my Web Apps connecting to KeyVault and the Azure SQL Server 
using Azure AD Application Token authentication so I know what is involved on that front.

When you check "Allow scripts to access OAuth token" on agent settings page,
can this token be used (using ADAL) to connect to KeyVault and SQL Server.
(Assuming the VisualStudioSPNxxx has the appropriate access to the above resources).

If not what should I be looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vsts token (Allow scripts to access OAuth token) can’t be used to connect to KeyVault.

You need to register app with Azure Active Directory and enable to communicate with Azure Active Directory and Key Vault, then get the connectionstring dynamically.

More information, you can refer to: [Protecting Secrets using VSTS and Azure Key Vault](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/03/28/protecting-secrets-using-vsts-and-azure-key-vault/)

Comment: Hi starain, so if I am to understand this correctly you need to Azure AD app registration/clientid/clientsecret to access KeyVault from a VSTS release?
What are the best practises/recommendations for securly storing the clientid and clientsecret on VSTS? Thanks

Comment: @DonalMcWeeney Yes. You can use security variable (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables#secret-variables).

Comment: Looks like the link is dead.

Comment: @Cody You can link Azure Key vaults to release: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=vsts

Comment: Thanks. Is there guidance on how to use this to inject the secrets into a separate secrets.config or secrets.json file, short of writing a script to do that?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT This link is broken. Can you please fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This is made relatively very easy now with Variable Groups - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=vsts

You can link a secret by connecting your Azure KV to a variable and then use this variable as you would normally use it in any script/task.